# select value from table as a new column

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Help me with sql

i have an table here:
[click here to see table](http://content.screencast.com/users/leracjobs/folders/Jing/media/f5915a8e-85e5-4c67-aae0-6390ad93f04c/2013-06-30_0120.png)

i want to add a new row
like this "[first name](http://content.screencast.com/users/leracjobs/folders/Jing/media/66d284c0-2d9b-4215-8069-77096c2a0629/2013-06-30_0327.png)"

meta_key = first_name and the coresponding meta_value
where basical looks like this

```
first name
----------
arnold
gear
john
dude
```

Comment: This is a **horribly bad** design - see [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid (point #3)](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) for a discussion of why EAV is really really bad, and see [Bad CaRMa](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=292) for a true horror story of an EAV system design that ruined a thriving company.

Comment: @marc_s If I understand correctly (which I'm not completely sure of) that's not an OP's own architectural choice. It's rather a reality of using WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name' THEN meta_value END) first_name,
       MIN(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'last_name'  THEN meta_value END) last_name
  FROM wp_usermeta
 WHERE meta_key IN ('first_name','last_name')
 GROUP BY user_id
```

Sample output:

```
| FIRST_NAME |  LAST_NAME |
---------------------------
|    Patrice | Fitzgerald |
|       Jhon |        Doe |
|       Mark |     (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffc8a/1)** demo